# Angular oauth2 oidc library, idp hint for correct identity provider

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak-services, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm using angular oauth2 oidc library for user identification inside of keycloak. Is it possible with this library to use idpHint to redirect to a valid identity provider?

I didn't find it as part of the config object, I don't know what else to look

Answer (score 0):

It [does not seem to be part of the library indeed](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/search?q=idphint), which at first glance makes sense since it's not part of [the OpenID Connect (core) spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) I think? Is `idpHint` perhaps a custom parameter for Keycloak?

For complete control you could create a subclass of the main service and override `createLoginUrl`, but you can also use [`customQueryParams`](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/3ba7303b5a6fdbae5ca214764c9191637cd00126/projects/lib/src/oauth-service.ts#L1584-L1589) ([see docs](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/custom-query-parameters.html)) if the value for idpHint is more stable. That depends on your situation (not really enough info in your question to tell which you'd need).

Comment: The parameter name for the Keycloak-idpHint-feature is `kc_idp_hint` and it must be passed to the `..openid-connect/auth?...` request. I guess the `customQueryParams` is the correct palace to put it. 

I do not know the angular oauth oidc library but in `oidc-client-ts` it can be solved as follows:

`const manager = new UserManager({ client_id: ..., extraQueryParams: {kc_idp_hint: "my-idp-hint"}})`

Comment: @MarcSchmid Thanks for your answer, it helped me solve a problem in my react project, I'm using the react-oidc-context lib which uses the oidc-client-ts lib.

For those who use the react-oidc-context lib, in the configuration object we must add extraQueryParams as mentioned previously.
`const oidcConfig = { authority: ..., client_id: ..., extraQueryParams: { kc_idp_hint: "saml"}`